# Storing current object in c++

Tags: c++

I want to store the currently selected object (selected by mouse click) and then implement methods on this object. The currently selected object is chosen from an array:

```
for(int i=0; i<trackList.size(); i++)
{
    trackList[i].setSelected(false);
    if((trackList[i].isClicked(x,y)) && (!trackList[i].isSelected()))
    {
        trackList[i].setSelected(true);
        currentSelected = trackList[i];
    }
}
```

I am new to C++ and have read up on pointers etc. but I am struggling to understand where and how they should be used. Do I need to have my currentSelected object as a pointer to whatever trackList[i] is?

Can I then implement methods on this object using the pointer reference?

Many thanks

EDIT:
trackList is storing a vector of Track objects:

```
std::vector<interface1::Track> trackList;
```

And currentSelected is storing a Track object which I want to apply methods to:

```
interface1::Track* currentSelected;
```

Comment: You don't show any details of what trackList is storing.  What is the type/class declaration?

Comment: Given information to answer your question is not enough. Maybe you should use pointer, maybe no.

Comment: From the given code sample, I can assume that you only set `currentSelected` once in the loop cycle. Could should probably (give the extent I can understand from the code) use the address of operator, i.e.: `currentSelected = &trackList[i];`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
 currentSelected = &(trackList[i]);
```

In order to assign the pointer the value of the address of `trackList[i]`.

Another way is to use iterators, like this:

```
std::vector<interface1::Track> trackList;
std::vector<interface1::Track>::iterator it, currentSelected;
for (it = trackList.begin(); it != trackList.end(); it++)
{
    it->setSelected(false);
    if((it->isClicked(x,y)) && (!it->isSelected()))
    {
        it->setSelected(true);
        currentSelected = it;
    }
}
```

Later you can use `currentSelected->setSelected(false);` for both the pointer and iterator.

Comment: Can I then call methods on the currentSelected pointer as normal to change member variable values, or do the methods have to be defined differently?

Comment: You need to call it like this: `currentSelected->setSelected(false);` which is deferencing a pointer.

Comment: One more thing, when running my program with these changes, I get "Access violation reading location .."?

Comment: It just says :
Unhandled exception at 0x00F04762 in Interface1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000054.

Comment: The use of currentSelected is only temporary. When currentSelected pointer goes out of scope, or if the vector is changed, then it may not be usable any more.

Comment: I have currentSelected defined in global scope though?

Comment: Have you tried to use it as an iterator instead of a pointer? I've used it like that in my programs.

Comment: Trying that I get vector iterator not deferencable?
p.s. thanks for being patient

Comment: Probably the vector has changed, and so your iterator is no longer pointing at the right place.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759274/what-is-the-lifetime-and-validity-of-c-iterators and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062956/checking-if-an-iterator-is-valid

Comment: So is there no way of doing what I want? The vector should change in terms of object position as it is created in my setup method. The objects member values will change but this shouldn't matter no?

Comment: Each time before using `currentSelected`, you can re-run the method above and update it.

Comment: That would rely on the track constantly being clicked for it to remain the currentSelected as it is clicking on the track object that assigns it to currentSelected

Comment: Or rather, go through the vector using `it` iterator and find the selected one and assign `currentSelected = it`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Oh well. Thanks so much for your help anyway, much appreciated.